# How to force download in MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a pdf and want to offer the user a simple "Download" link.
How can this be made?

My idea is
- to compute the url to the pdf document on server side and store it in "viewmodel.PDFURL",
- add a `<a href=...>` to the view which calls a function.
- This function would use

```
$.post("ForcePDFDownload", { PDFURL: <%: Model.PDFURL %> } );
```

to call this serverside method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ForcePDFDownload(string PDFURL)
{
    string path = Path.GetFullPath(PDFURL);
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(PDFURL);
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.WriteFile(path);
    Response.End();

    return null;
}
```

But `return null;` makes no sense to me, but the methode must return something, otherwise wont Visual Studio compile...

Any idea?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use JSON, ajax, jquery or whatever. Simply:

```
public ActionResult ForcePDFDownload(string PDFURL)
{
    string path = Path.GetFullPath(PDFURL);
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(PDFURL);
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    return File(path, "application/pdf");
}
```

And then construct a link:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Download PDF", "ForcePDFDownload", new { PDFURL = Model.PDFURL }) %>
```

Be extremely careful when exposing such action on your server as a hacker could always type the following address in his favorite browser:

```
http://foo.com/somecontroller/forcepdfdownload/?pdfurl=c%3A%5Cmycreditcardnumbers.txt
```

and live happily to the rest of his life :-)

Comment: WOW! That was fast and really good!
Thanky ou very much! Works!